# Automatically crop image after save in rails with predefined height, width, and (x , y) index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, resize, paperclip, crop

[image: I want to remove blue extra background automatically not manually]
 I am searching the way to automatically crop image after save of Image:

I came across a tedious problem when transforming html to image in rails.
**My problem is when html is converted to image then extra background is also appended to image**, which I don't need so trying to crop image after save callback through some code.

I need answer specific to the problem, any help will be appriciated.

Thanks In Advance

Friends I povided the solution to answer below but I need more efficient and effective than my provided solution.

1) I want to do in shorter lines

2) With little cost of croping

3) Efficient algo

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the graphic independent of the html page?

Comment: when creating image I gave width:240px and height:200px; so as per my understanding there may be some crope method. img.crop(width,height,x,y) where x,y are starting point to crop with value x=y=0
something like that what i exactly need

Answer (score 0):

I think the most proper way is to use ImageMagic , which has its own scripting language (or API ) . Take a look at this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/374-image-manipulation?autoplay=true). It uses CarrierWawe , I don't think it would be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

After saving image I called this method to crop image

```
def reprocess_final_image

    image_file_url = Rails.root.to_s+'/public'+self.final_image.url(:original).split('?')[0]
    img = Magick::Image.read(image_file_url).first
    img.format = "PNG"
    img.crop_resized!(240,200, Magick::NorthWestGravity)
    img.write(image_file_url)


  end
```

where Crop resized method have parameters 
img.crop_resized!(width,height,Gravity)

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) provide an awesome service for this kind of thing. Easy peasy integration with Heroku too!

Comment: that is third party tool and are we supposed to use them?

Comment: Yes, it's a third party tool. It provides image processing and hosting of your images (for a price)